# Can't see CSS in phoenix's ex_admin plugin

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch, elixir-mix

Trying to install [ex_admin](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin) for Phoenix.  Having followed the directions on the following githubs:

- [ex_admin](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin)
- [ex_admin demo](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin_demo)
- [ex_admin survey tutorial](https://github.com/smpallen99/elixir_survey_tutorial)

...whenever I go to `/admin` the css is unformatted; it's just black-on-white html.  I have tried pointing brunch to the modules' assets directly:

#### ex_admin_demo/brunch-config.js

```
paths: {
  // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
  watched: [
   "web/static",
   "test/static",
   "deps/ex_admin/web/static"
 ],
```

...but this doesn't seem to work either.  Is there a manual brunch override that needs to take place here, or is there some other way to tell brunch to read the `/dep/ex_admin/` assets?

Comment: Did you run `mix admin.install`?

Comment: Yes...and just realized that ex_admin adds a bunch of commented content to the bottom of brunch-config.  That worked.  Ugh, that was obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `mix admin.install` it will append your `brunch-config.js` file with a number of comments explaining the changes you need to make in your `brunch-config.js` file to get the ex_admin assets compile. That should fix your issue.

The is an outstanding pull request that include the assets automatically. Once its merged, you will not need this step.